# In a finite quantum well with a constant electric field, is it possible to find a bound state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

You have this equation
$-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2}+(V(x)-eFx)\Psi=E \Psi$  where $V(x)$ is the potential for a finite quantum well.

Is there solution which is a real bound state, I mean there is no possibility of quantum tunellling. I think that there is no a real bound state because the electric field is defined in all the space, so you always can find a unbound state of the same energy or less energy and you can reach that state through quantum tunelling.

Comment: OK, so your Hamiltonian is not bounded from below and there are indeed no bound states. However,  in such cases (Stark effect!) the tunneling probability can be rather small when the particle is initially sitting near the bottom of the potential well, corresponding to a "metastable state".

Comment: Thanks for answering, that makes sense to me and also matches my initial intuition.

Comment: … looks like a problem where the variational approach might provide insight into the existence of a bound state (but not disprove the non-existence).